# mysql and socket interaction in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, database, socket.io, connection

I'm writing a simple online videogame with node js and I want to manage the score of each player saving it in a database(mysql).

Now in the server side I have a piece of code like this:

```
    socket.on('game_over',function(data){
        for (var i = 0; i < players.length; i++) {
            if(players[i].id == data.id){
                var sql;    
                sql='UPDATE login SET email=? WHERE username=?'
                connection.query(sql, [data.score,"d"],function(error, results, fields) {
                    console.log(sql);
                    console.log(error);
                if (error) throw error;
                console.log(result);
            });
                players.splice(i,1);
                break;
            }
        }
        socket.broadcast.emit('p_disconnect',data.id);

    });
```

When I start my server and a game_over signal is recived, my server disconnect.
The print of the sql query is correct and I don't see any error since it return me 'null'

Why my server disconnect after that, and more importantly what can I do to keep the server up?

Without the connection.query part it works like it should

Comment: First of all I don't think that `.splice()` the array on which you are looping on is a good idea. Is correct that the `p_disconnect` event is emitted basically istantly as response of the `game_over` one, without waiting for the query?

Comment: If you need to find the correct player you can use `players.find(p => p.id === data.id)`

Comment: @AndreaFranchini isn't p_disconnect emitted after the query? (anyway it doesn't matter). Regarding the slice I didn't think to it (I still need to find a solution)

Comment: @AndreaFranchini I need to find the correct player and delete it from the list of the active players and update the database with it's score. I'm learning javascript, nodejs etc while doing this project that's probably why I don't see how your code can do that sry

Answer (score -1):

Based on the comment on the question:

```
// assuming 
const players = [
  {id: 1, otherInfo: 'foobar' },
  {id: 2, otherInfo: 'foobar' },
]

const connection = mysql.connect() // something like this

// When the game ends we assume that the game_over event is fired
socket.on('game_over',function (data) {

    // "I need to find the correct player"
    const correctPlayer = players.find(player => player.id === data.id)

    // "and delete it from the list of the active players"
    const position = players.indexOf(correctPlayer)
    players.splice(position, 1)

    // "and update the database with it's score" => depends on your DB structure
    const query = `UPDATE youTable SET score = ${data.score} WHERE playerId = ${correctPlayer.id}`


    // here depends on how you want to manage the query result (some examples)


    // run query (is async cause how js works) and just log the result
    connection.query(sql, function(error, results, fields) {
      // this code is executed when the query ends
      console.log(error, results, fields)
    }
    // this code is executed after starting the query
    socket.broadcast.emit('p_disconnect', data.id);


    // run query and emit event after the query ends
    connection.query(sql, function(error, results, fields) {
      socket.broadcast.emit('p_disconnect', data.id);
      console.log(error, results, fields)
    }
});
```